# Ignore RequestBody value based on condition

Tags: java, spring, reactjs

I am passing an object and receiving as a `RequestBody` annotation of spring framework. But I want to pass a value for hashmap which will attach as a key value pair to the object in a pojo also I have ENUM as a second variable.

My Pojo:

```
private CommandConstants command; // enum
private HashMap<String,String> commandArgs; //hashmap
```

Where `CommandConstants` is a enum just a command to receive as String.

```
const res= await axios.post(configs.Data.handleControl, { command:action, 

commandArgs: ((action==="MAKE_ALL_SANDWICHES" || 
action==="FLIP_ALL_BURGERS") && [{}]) ||((action==="TOAST_SANDWICH" && 
addBurger!==null) && [{key:"BURGERCOUNT", value:addBurger}])||

((action==="MAKE_SANDWICH" || action==="SPOIL_SANDWICH" || 
action==="FLIP_BURGER") && [{key:"TOASTERID", value:toasterId}]) ||

(action==="MARINATE_BURGER" && [{key:"CATEGORY", 
value:wired?"WIRED":"WIRELESS"},{key:wired?"WIRED":"WIRELESS", value:wired?
wired:wireless}]) ||(action==="RUST_BURGER" && [{key:"CATEGORY", 
value:wired?"WIRED":"WIRELESS"},{key:wired?"WIRED":"WIRELESS", value:wired?
wired:wireless}])});
```

Ignore things which is not required.

**Actual Result:**

```
{"command":"MAKE_ALL_SANDWICHES","commandArgs":[{"key":null,"value":null}]}
```

**Expected Result:**

```
{"command":"START_ALL_MACHINES"}`
```

can I ignore POJO variables like above if it is `null`?

Maybe I made a mistake in my reactjs part

The unexpected result I am getting only in two action where command is `MAKE_ALL_SANDWICHES` or `FLIP_ALL_BURGERS` since only in these two cases where I am not passing anything any **commandArgs**

Comment: Did you take a look how the exact request body looks like? Does it contains nothing for commandArgs? You can easily do it with developer tools of any browser.

Comment: @AlexeyUsharovski Yes I looked and the thing only in case of two action which condtions I have written and mentioned in above question the data should not pass anything at backend therefore want to ignore commandArgs

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood the question correctly, but if you do not want null values to be passed by the server to the client in the body then you could annotate your POJO class with: `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` and they should be filtered out.